# postgres function will run fine in psql console, but hangs when executed in a script

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.4

I have a function that runs through a loop and calls another function (I've also tried this with all the code within the same function).  The inner function runs through another loop and does inserts on a non-temp table.

What happens is.. when I call this function in psql prompt, it runs with no problem, with a consistent speed.

When I call it from within a script like in

```
psql -e -f do_stuff_including_run_function.sql
```

it runs for a while, seems to slow down and then basically just hang there, no errors thrown.  The whole process takes 1.5 hours in the console, and when attempted to run from a script, it went over 30 hours after which I've killed the process.  Nothing else was running on the system that could've created an access conflict. 
I've checked for any locks and found nothing indicating a problem.

Any ideas anyone?